# copying file using super user access

Tags: gtk, gnome

I have a file which needs to be copied into **file system** of ubuntu OS 10.10 from a gtk program. I can copy from terminal using sudo, but my requirement is i have to use gtk or gnome framework.

Thanks in advance
iSight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch nautilus with [`gksudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo):

```
gksudo nautilus
```

Create a file names `nautilus_root.desktop` in `~/Desktop` with the following contents to create a desktop shortcut:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=nautilus as root
Comment=Launch nautilus as root user
Icon=system-file-manager
Exec=gksudo nautilus
Type=Application
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
NoDisplay=true
```

Comment: is it command gksudo nautilus has to be run on terminal. If so, that does not resolve my issue.

Comment: @iSight If you create a desktop shortcut then you don't have to use the terminal at all.

Comment: @marcog: i got that. but when another user execute my application on his machine then what should i do for it so that the file is copied to that location.

Comment: @iSight Try it out and you should see very quickly. If not, come back and I'll help you understand.

Comment: @marcog: i have executed gksudo nautilus, then new window with root folder opens then wat i have to do...

Comment: @iSight You now have root privileges (or super user access as you call it). Find the file you want to copy and copy it.

Comment: k i got it, i can directly copy and paste to any location in file system. Thanks again.

Comment: @marcog: then, wat about copying using a file from gtk+ program.

Comment: @iSight You mean an application you wrote?

Comment: @marcog: ya that's right, i have wrote one program using gtk+, so during its execution that file needs to be copied into file system.

Comment: @iSight You have it then, use [libgksu](http://www.nongnu.org/gksu/). Read the [docs](http://people.debian.org/~kov/gksu/reference/libgksu-API-Reference.html). I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`gksu`](http://live.gnome.org/gksu/) to wrap `su` and `sudo` calls.